# Problem reading in strings as factors; the preceding spaces seem to matter

Tags: r

Having a problem reading in a textConnection() mini-file that has factors.  This fragment below makes two separate factors for 'LabAuto'.

```
x <- read.table(tc <- textConnection(
"Project, TestingType, CodeType
'TS',     'TDDEUT',    Production
'TS',     'TDDEUT',    Testing
'NR',      'LabAuto',  Production
'In',     'LabAuto',   Testing"),
    header=TRUE, colClasses=c("character", "factor", "factor"),
    sep=",", na.strings=c("NULL"), quote="'")
```

TestingType shows this, indicating there are two levels labeled (approximately) LabAuto:

```
> x$TestingType
[1]      TDDEUT        TDDEUT         LabAuto      LabAuto 
Levels:       LabAuto      LabAuto      TDDEUT
```

Ostensibly this is due to the extra space in front of the first 'LabAuto' factor, because if I remove one space (on the 'NR' line), then I just end up with two factors for TestingType, as I want:

```
> x$TestingType
[1]      TDDEUT       TDDEUT       LabAuto      LabAuto
Levels:      LabAuto      TDDEUT
```

But shouldn't specifying the sep="," and quote="'" parameters have told R to only consider the text **inside the single-quotes** as the factor label?

The single quotes are not exclusively the problem, as the third column above has the same issue:

```
> x$CodeType
[1]     Production     Testing      Production      Testing    
Levels:     Production     Testing    Testing   Production
```

It shows 4 different factors instead of 2, again ostensibly because there are differing numbers of spaces in front of each.  Is there a way to tell R to ignore spaces when making factor levels out of a text input file?  Thanks.

Comment: From `?read.table` you can ostensibly set `strip.white = TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file is in a very strange format. Normally you either have a delimiter or spaces separating values. You seem to have both which is odd. But you can strip out the space if you use the `strip.white=` parameter to `read.table`. Use

```
x <- read.table(tc <- textConnection(
  "Project, TestingType, CodeType
'TS',     'TDDEUT',    Production
'TS',     'TDDEUT',    Testing
'NR',      'LabAuto',  Production
'In',     'LabAuto',   Testing"),
  header=TRUE, colClasses=c("character", "factor", "factor"),
  sep=",", na.strings=c("NULL"), quote="'", strip.white = TRUE)

x$TestingType
# [1] TDDEUT  TDDEUT  LabAuto LabAuto
# Levels: LabAuto TDDEUT
```

Comment: strip.white was the answer.  Thank you!  The data is formatted that way because I edit it by hand on occasion.  Helps to have columns lined up.  Strings or factors may have embedded spaces.